# Displaying canvas between div background image and rest of div content

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to display a canvas, specifically a [Granim.js](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/index.html) canvas, between a Div background image and the other contents of the Div.

So, there would be a background image, then the Granim.js canvas with the opacity turned down on top of that and then text, gallery, button etc. on top of that.

Here is the code for the Div I'm working with:

```
    <section class="bg-image" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="container" id="carousel">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                            <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
                            <hr class="light">
                            <p>Take a look at my portfolio on Béhance!<br>It contains my freelance projects as well as some of the work I did for X and Y.</p>                              

                            <!-- Carousel Card -->
                            <div class="card card-raised card-carousel">
                                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                                        <!-- Indicators -->
                                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                        </ol>

                                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                            <div class="item active">
                                                <img src="img/gallery/bg2.jpeg" alt="Awesome Image">
                                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                    <h4>UI/UX Design for Web & Mobile</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="img/gallery/bg3.jpeg" alt="Awesome Image">
                                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                    <h4>Online Advertising</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="img/gallery/bg4.jpeg" alt="Awesome Image">
                                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                    <h4>Corporate Identity & Branding</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Controls -->
                                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Carousel Card -->

                            <hr class="invis">
                            <a href="https://www.behance.net/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Visit Portfolio</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
```

CSS for div with bg image:

```
.bg-image {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/portfolio_bg2.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
```

and here is the code to add the canvas:

```
<canvas id="granim-canvas"></canvas>
```

The canvas does work in isolation elsewhere on the page so there's no problem there. It's just layering things the way I want to that's the issue.

Here's the code for the Granim.js canvas just in case it helps:

````
## How to use
```html
<!-- Create a <canvas> element -->
<canvas id="granim-canvas"></canvas>

<!-- Call the script -->
<script src="granim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create a Granim instance -->
<script>
var granimInstance = new Granim({
   element: '#granim-canvas',
   name: 'granim',
   opacity: [0.7, 0.7],
   states : {
       "default-state": {
           gradients: [
               ['#834D9B', '#D04ED6'],
               ['#1CD8D2', '#93EDC7']
           ]
       }
   }
});
</script>
````

Comment: Do you want the canvas behind everything else? Add a `float:left` and it won't take any space. Or, have it like this: `<div class="background-stuff"><canvas></canvas><div style="position: absolute; top: 0"></div></div>` (It might be relative, I forgot)

Comment: @Artyer I want to have an image at the very back, the canvas in front of that and then the normal div content ( text, buttons etc.) at the very front.

Granim.js is an animated gradient canvas. I thought it would be cool to have that animating in front of the background image.